# Difference in Behavior with tf.variable_scope in TF Version 1.0.0

Tags: tensorflow

Previously `tf.variable_scope` threw an error if variables were defined with the same name and the `reuse` parameter was not set to `True`. This no longer seems to be true in TF 1.0.0. The following minimum example shows this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import layers
print(tf.__version__)

def net(in_data, reuse=None):
    with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=reuse):
        return layers.conv2d(in_data, 3, 3)

in_data = tf.random_uniform([10, 40, 30, 3])
out_data1 = net(in_data)
out_data2 = net(in_data, reuse=None)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    rval = sess.run([out_data1, out_data2])
```

TF ver 0.12.0 gives the following error:

> ValueError: Variable foo/Conv/weights already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope?

TF ver 1.0.0 executes without error. Is this an intended change in behavior? If so, how should this type of error be raised in ver 1.0?

Note that this effect seems to be associated with `tf.contrib.layers` and `tf.contrib.slim`. `tf.layers` doesn't show the same issue. Why???

Comment: That might have been a bug. In general, the `contrib` directory is not well supported, so it's best to use `tf.layers`.